# The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods

Tags: remix, metamask, ganache, jquery

Hi I'm having this error when I try to set a variable in remix.

```
inpage.js:1 Uncaught Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_sendTransaction without a callback parameter. See https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#dizzy-all-async---think-of-metamask-as-a-light-client for details.
at MetamaskInpageProvider.send (inpage.js:1)
at s.send (inpage.js:1)
at n.e [as sendTransaction] (inpage.js:1)
at u.sendTransaction (inpage.js:1)
at u.execute (inpage.js:1)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (index.html:93)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
```

This is my code in script

```
  <script>
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
    }
    web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];

    var CoursetroContract = web3.eth.contract([
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "_fName",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "_age",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "setInstructor",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "getInstructor",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
}]);
    var Coursetro = CoursetroContract.at('0xdfae0c09d27d0614cc337b821be4370d9ec2d7c6');
    console.log(Coursetro);

      Coursetro.getInstructor(function(error, result){
        if(!error)
            {
                $("#instructor").html(result[0]+' ('+result[1]+' years old)');
                console.log(result);
            }
    });

    $("#button").click(function() {
        Coursetro.setInstructor($("#name").val(), $("#age").val());
    });
</script>
```

This is the first time I encounter this problem because I'm new in making dapps. Any answer will be accepted and appreciated. Thank you and sorry about my english. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a callback function, e.g.:

```
Coursetro.setInstructor($("#name").val(), $("#age").val(), function (err, result) {
  console.log(err, result);
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir this answer my problem. :)  Last question sir can I run metamask with free balance? Just for testing dapps?  And if yes how?